# Trying to replace regular expression string with 0 space

Tags: java, jmeter

For the string  {"s":4,"v": I have created regular expression :{"s":[0-9]+,"v" and I am trying to replace it with zero space with the code below

```
 String str ; 
 str = str.replaceAll("{"s":[0-9]+,"v":", "");
```

but it is failing please correct my code

Comment: For starters you need to escape the internal double quotes since they are inside double quotes for the whole expression..

Comment: "{\"s\":[0-9]+,\"v\":"

Comment: String str =""; 
  str = str.replace("{\"s\":[0-9],\"v\":", "");

Comment: Fails in what way? Please paste the incorrect result or hte error message that you are getting into the question. Always do that when asking about code that doesn’t work on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Type `""` and then paste `{"s":4,"v":` between quotes. Your IDE will automatically escape the quotes within the string for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape double quotes inside String by backslash.

Because of brace is a metacharacter in RegEx, you have to use escape backslash: `\{`. But if you put this in a String you have to escape backslash itself. That's why you have to put double backslash before the left brace: `\\{`.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{\"s\":[0-9]+,\"v\":", "");
```